# Using *NgIf only displays button but not the text

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I try displaying either a confirm or a cancel button based on a boolean I'm setting in my component.ts. For that I implement following code in my HTML:

```
    <mat-dialog-actions class="dialog-actions">
        <button  class="cancel-btn" (click)="closeDialog(false)" [mat-dialog-close]="false" color="warn" mat-raised-button>
      {{cancelButtonText}}
    </button>

        <button *ngIf="!cancelOnly" id="dialog-confirm-button" class="confirm-btn" (click)="closeDialog(true)" [mat-dialog-close]="true" color="accent" mat-raised-button>
            {{ confirmButtonText }}
        </button>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
```

And this in my component.ts:

```
    public openReset(): void {
        const dialogData = {
            headline: this.translate.instant('APP.RESET'),
            content: this.resetDialogContent,
            cancelOnly: true,
            cancelButtonText: this.translate.instant('APP.CANCEL'),
        };

        this.ui.openDialog(dialogData, { disableClose: false }, (confirmed) => {
            //implement logic here
        });
    }
```

It is creating the cancel or confirm button based on the boolean im setting in cancelOnly but somehow the text of cancelButtonText which im also setting is not showing.
When typing plain text it is showing and when removing the *NgIf the cancelButtonText is also shwoing.
Only the *NgIf and the cancelButtonText in combination is not working. Does anybody have an idea why that is?

Here are some example pictures of how it look and should look like:

[Picture with no text but button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bYiw.png)
\n
[Picture with text and button but no *NgIf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SDuL.png)

I tried tracking down every attribute and they're set properly. I can just not get behind it, why the text is not showing.

Comment: Nothing seems incorrect to me. Could you please either show us some more code (especially the ts file) or ideally a Minimal Reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?

Comment: I don't find any thing wrong into the code, if possible please provide more code detail. In case please also try using "ngShow" or "ngHide" instead of "ngIf".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my problem. I used this in my HTML file:

```
<ng-template #stationDialogContent>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="resetForm" class="factoryResetDialog">
            <span>Wirklich zurücksetzen?</span>
        </button>
    </mat-form-field>
</ng-template>
``

And the problem was the button inside the mat-form-field. By removing that it is working fine.
```